# Disable loading screen in Flowplayer

Tags: javascript, html, flowplayer

I have a flowplayer that plays a jpg file for two seconds and then plays a plugin.
When the player is loading it shows a circle and controls.
Is there a way to disable this loading screen or show an image instead?
UPD: seems there is no way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by customizing the logo animation, however to do so you need to buy the commercial version as the community version lacks this functionality you can read more about it [here](http://flowplayer.org/documentation/skinning/branding.html).

Hope it helps.

Comment: I do have the commercial version. I don't mean the flowplayer logo that disappears. Could you be more specific, pls.